# Sending request from postman to Spring OAuth2 app

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I have created simplest spring oauth2 application. Here is all(!) my code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Oauth2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Oauth2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: clientId
            clientSecret: clientSecret
```

And I want to send a request to my hello endpoint via Postman.

I have filled all required fields in the OAuth2 tab and generated my token. I can see my token in the Authorization header, but still, my request to localhost:8080 fails and returns me GitHub login page. What am I doing wrong?

I have also generated token by myself by sending direct requests to Github auth URL and access token URL and this token didn't work for my app but worked for Github API.

Also interesting, is that when I am sending a request from a browser, it prompts me to the login page, I am logging in to Github and it redirects me to initial the page, I can't see any Authorization headers in all those requests. Only JSESSIONID cookie.

Please, guys, I would appreciate any ideas on how to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gilles is right, you are writing a OAuth2 `resource-server`, not a `client`.

You can hardly use Github as authorization-server for your resource-server: it issues "opaque" tokens (not JWTs) which you can't use easily with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` or alike (I don't know any introspection endpoint for Github tokens).

An option for you is using an OIDC authorization-server of your own (like Keycloak) capable of "user identity federation": it will proxy Github (and any other common identity provider you like: Google, Facebook, etc.).

Once you have an authorization-server issuing JWT access-tokens, you can have a look at those tutorials to configure your resource-server:

- [resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken)
- [resource-server_with_oauthentication](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (requires more Java config)

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a response as I don't have enough reputation to add a comment but it's more a hint than a response...

First regarding the fact that you are not able to find the Authorization header when you look at the exchanges between the browser and your backend.
I don't have it either but in the cookies of my request I have a **KEYCLOCK_IDENTITY** cookie (my idp is Keycloak as you probably guessed).
It should hold the informations needed to ensure that you are who you are (at least it's my understanding of the presence of this cookie).
Maybe you have something like this but related to Google ?

Second thing: it looks like you want to use your SpringBoot application as a resource server, you should probably take a look at this [page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html) and use the **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server** dependency instead of the **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client** dependency in order to make it work with an HTTP client like Postman.

I hope it helps.